# ¿Como puedo hacer pedir un solo dato de una tabla de mysql con el id desde php?

Tags: php, mysqli

lo que estoy haciendo es el apartado de los comentarios pero al hacer el select from me da todos los datos lo que quiero es poder ingresar el id de comentario asi como comentario 1 comentario 2 etc y que muestre solo ese comentario

Comment: Hola @Fabian por favor puedes colocar el código que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora para poderte ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM nombreTabla WHERE idComentario='.$idComentario.';';
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes filtrar tu consulta sql con un "where" por ejemplo:

```
select dato 
  from tabla 
  where id = $id
```